Any way to use Angular's HttpClientTestingModule on code with awaits?
I'm trying to add unit tests to legacy code and noticed that if the code uses "await" I need to call a tick or flushMicrotask between each httpTestingController's expect.  Here is the component:
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-t-comp',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './t-comp.component.html',
  styleUrl: './t-comp.component.scss'
})
export class TCompComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    // this passes tests
    this.init();

    // this fails tests
    // this.initAwaits();
  }


  init(): void {
    this.http.post('http://www.google.com', new HttpHeaders()).subscribe(googleResponse => {
      console.log(googleResponse);
      this.http.post('http://www.facebook.com', new HttpHeaders()).subscribe(facebookResponse => {
        console.log(facebookResponse);
      });
    });
  }

  async initAwaits(): Promise<void> {
    const googleResponse = await firstValueFrom(this.http.post('http://www.google.com', new HttpHeaders()));
    console.log(googleResponse);
    const facebookResponse = await firstValueFrom(this.http.post('http://www.facebook.com', new HttpHeaders()));
    console.log(facebookResponse);
  }
}
    

And the following test:
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { TCompComponent } from './t-comp.component';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

describe('TCompComponent', () => {
  let component: TCompComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TCompComponent>;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [TCompComponent, HttpClientTestingModule]
    })
      .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TCompComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    // After every test, assert that there are no more pending requests.
    httpTestingController.verify();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();

    httpTestingController.expectOne({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://www.google.com',
    }, 'Google').flush({});

    // if i call initAwaits i need to tick or flush and turn this test into fakeAsync
    httpTestingController.expectOne({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://www.facebook.com',
    }, 'Facebook').flush({});
  });
});

Is there any way around this?  I would like to define all my client testing modules expects and then have the component finish.  It would be ok to call tick or flush once at the end, but needing to get the timing between each expect is almost impossible.

Both ways are inefficient, because the requests could be made simultaneously, but they are made sequentially. Also for the Observables case you are creating two subscriptions. Why don't you use forkJoin()? Also is there no chance to improve the existing code, especially when you are adding tests?

Posted was just a short code example to demonstrate problem.  Imagine needing to run 2 sequential calls when the user clicks a button.  You could use nested subscriptions, or chose to use use awaits - I would consider that a coding preference but functionally the same.  I would prefer to keep my unit test implementation generic - write the unit test, then be able refactor and have it pass both before and after.  Having to call the ticks makes the unit test specific to a solution
